# Mongoose aggregation with geonear

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to implement paging with Mongoose geoNear command. It seem skip is not supported with geoNear, and I understand aggregation would work (with paging with a performance cost). How can I convert this to aggregation query to skip a number of documents?

```
exports.near = function(req, res) {
    if(req.query.lat && req.query.lng) {
        var point = {
            type: "Point", coordinates : [Number(req.query.lng), Number(req.query.lat)]
        };
        var queryParams = {
            spherical: true,
            skip: 0,
            limit: 10,
            distanceMultiplier: 6371 // radians to kilometers. (The radius of the Earth is approximately 3,959 miles or 6,371 kilometers.)
        };
        if(req.query.q) {
            var matcher = new RegExp(req.query.q, "i");
            queryParams.query = {
                $or: [
                    {'name': matcher },
                    {'address.full': matcher}
                ]
            };
        }
        if(req.query.limit) {
            queryParams.limit = parseInt(req.query.limit, 10);
        }
        if(req.query.offset) {
            queryParams.skip = parseInt(req.query.offset, 10);
        }
        Venue.geoNear(point, queryParams, function(error, results, stats) {
            // TODO
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework for this and there is no real penalty as the operations are essentially the same.

But while the mongoose `.find()` method presently has a problem with the [**`$nearSphere`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) operator which is equivalent, you can always grab the raw node driver connection object and do your query.

You do not even need to throw away things like "population" if you are prepared to implement a little handling.

Here is my test data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "P1",
    "amenity" : "restaurant", 
    "shape" : { 
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [ 2, 2 ] 
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : "P3",
    "amenity" : "police",
    "shape" : { 
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [ 4, 2 ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : "P4",
    "amenity" : "police",
    "shape" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 4, 4 ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : "P2",
    "amenity" : "restaurant",
    "shape" : { 
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 2, 4 ]
    }, 
    "info" : ObjectId("539b90543249ff8d18e863fb")
}
```

And the basic code to handle this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    async = require('async'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

var infoSchema = new Schema({
  "description": String
});

var shapeSchema = new Schema({
  "_id": String,
  "amenity": String,
  "shape": {
    "type": { "type": String },
    "coordinates": []
  },
  "info": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Info" }
});

var Shape = mongoose.model( "Shape", shapeSchema );
var Info = mongoose.model( "Info", infoSchema );


Shape.collection.find(
  {
    "shape": {
      "$nearSphere": {
        "$geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [ 2, 4 ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "skip": 0, "limit": 2
  },
  function(err,cursor) {

    cursor.toArray(function(err,shapes) {

      Shape.populate( shapes, { path: "info" }, function(err,docs) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log( JSON.stringify( docs, undefined, 4 ) );
      });

    });

  }
);
```

So there you got usage of both the **skip** and **limit** operations on the cursor, had a cursor returned and even processed the documents back into "Mongoose Documents" so you can call functions like `.populate()` on them.

I would expect the current issue with [**`$nearSphere`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) to be fixed relatively soon though.

Or using aggregate instead:

```
Shape.aggregate(
  [
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [ 2, 4 ]
        },
        "spherical": true,
        "distanceField": "dis"
    }},
    { "$skip": 0 },
    { "$limit": 2 }

  ],
  function(err,shapes) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //console.log( shapes );

    shapes = shapes.map(function(x) {
      delete x.dis;
      return new Shape( x );
    });

    Shape.populate( shapes, { path: "info" }, function(err,docs) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log( JSON.stringify( docs, undefined, 4 ) );
    });

  }
);
```

Where you can do the same things such as use `.populate()`. Both cases return results like this with the "populated" field matched:

```
{
    "_id": "P2",
    "amenity": "restaurant",
    "info": {
        "_id": "539b90543249ff8d18e863fb",
        "description": "Jamies Restaurant",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "shape": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            2,
            4
        ]
    }
},
{
    "info": null,
    "_id": "P4",
    "amenity": "police",
    "shape": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            4,
            4
        ]
    }
}
```

Of course if you do not need the spherical geometry calculation then the [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator works perfectly fine with the Mongoose implementation of `.find()`

Comment: Thanks Neil, I've updated my code to use your aggregation example: http://pastie.org/9335513 this solved my paging problem. But calculated distances have changed, do you have any idea why that would be the case? Also what I meant by performance cost was this: http://emptysqua.re/blog/paging-geo-mongodb/ Do you think this way of paging has the same performance penalty?

Comment: @strada Not too sure what you mean by distances changed or even really why you need to use the aggregate command when there are no other operations being performed other than the selection and paging. You can do this with a standard query. Perhaps by "distance" you are not taking into account that the aggregate method issues raidans. Paging performance is always relative to how many "pages deep" you are actually going. The  cost of skipping is generally mitigated by "range queries" instead, or by "blacklisting" seen documents as is basically pointed out in the post mentioned.

Comment: How can i get the distance with find query ?

Answer (score 0):

```
location.aggregate({"$geoNear": { "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [parseFloat(req.params.lon), parseFloat(req.params.lat)] }, "maxDistance":500, 'distanceField' : 'distance', spherical: true
      }}, 
    function(err, places) {
   if(!err){
           console.log(places);
            res.send('({"records":' + JSON.stringify(places) + '});');
        }
        else{
            console.log(err);
            res.send("error coming")
        }
    });`

Above Query working fine in mongo shell but not working in mongoose
```