# Mongodb limit function for multiple fields on regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to have a limit on each field itself when using collection.find(). 
In below example I can place a limit as a method for find, but how to perform it on each field accordingly. Is this available in mongodb?

```
        var collection = db.collection('collAutocomplete');
        collection.find({
            $or: [{
                "Town": new RegExp(searchKey, 'i')  //Can I put a limit here?
            }, {
                "State": new RegExp(searchKey, 'i')  //Can I put a limit here?
            }, {
                "Nation": new RegExp(searchKey, 'i')  //Can I put a limit here?
            }]
        }).limit(3)   //I can put a limit here..
        .toArray()function(err, item) { }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have limits on conditions as you described. You basically want `top n` on multiple conditions, so you can solve the problem in different ways, but I doubt there is a "single query" solution for this.

You could use multiple queries or use the aggregation framework to build arrays for your `regex`-s then get your result from there.

You should take a look at [Multiple limit condition in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567330/multiple-limit-condition-in-mongodb) as well.