# MongoDB how to limit the results for each group / category / condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a database of product inventory stating the status of each product instance.

```
[
  { prod: A, location: 1, status: 1 },
  { prod: A, location: 1, status: 2 },
  { prod: A, location: 2, status: 1 },
  { prod: A, location: 3, status: 1 },
  { prod: B, location: 2, status: 2 },
  { prod: B, location: 1, status: 1 },
  { prod: B, location: 1, status: 2 },
  { prod: B, location: 1, status: 2 },
  { prod: C, location: 1, status: 1 }
]
```

And we have some dynamic query pair like

```
[A: 2, B: 4]
```

where the digit is the result limit for the corresponding product. (meaning we want two As and four Bs) (and of course there can be Cs and Ds etc.)

Now I know in aggregation we can match status=1 and prod %in% [A,B].

And we can put a overall $limit on the whole query result like filtering 10 entries only.

And $slice is not useful too since it cannot take multiple parameters.


**So, must I do multiple queries or is there an efficient way to do this in one aggregation?**

(I have searched a lot and seems we only have solutions for top N results for every group.

example: [Multiple limit condition in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567330/multiple-limit-condition-in-mongodb) )


**EDIT:**


To clarify, basically I want different limits for different products.

This is what I can do, using a for-loop to do multiple queries.

But is there a way to do it in **one aggregation without looping**?

```
q = {A:2, B:4};
allResult = [];
Object.keys(q).forEach(k => {
    result = db.find({prod:k}).limit(q[k]).exec();  //find for one prod
    allResult = allResult.concat(result);
});
```

Expected output:

```
[
  { prod: A, location: 1, status: 1 },
  { prod: A, location: 1, status: 2 },
  { prod: B, location: 2, status: 2 },
  { prod: B, location: 1, status: 1 },
  { prod: B, location: 1, status: 2 },
  { prod: B, location: 1, status: 2 }
]
```