# Mongoose limit by association

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
[
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 10 },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 20 },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 30 },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 40 },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 50 },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 60 },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 10 },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 13 },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 14 },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 15 },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 10 },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 100 },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 200 },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 300 }
]
```

Given a query with relevant parent ids, `['b','c']`, I need to get back the first 3 results for each parent, hopefully DESC-sorted by `w`:

```
[
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 15 },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 14 },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 13 },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 300 },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 200 },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 100 }
]
```

Using `.find()` and `.limit()` would return the first N results overall, not the first N for each `parent`. Using `.aggregate()` I figured out how to aggregate by `parent` but I couldn't figure out how to `$limit` by parent, nor how to return the entire documents as `{parent: 'b', items: [{..}, {..}] }` instead of just the group data. I can get either `parent`, which I already had, or maybe `parent` and an array on some field using `$push`, but that's still no good.

Lastly I also tried `.mapReduce` but that seems like overkill, wouldn't I have to `emit(this.project, this);` for the aggregation part? how would I even $limit on that? by hand? It's quite underdocumented.

Anyways, some direction on which way to go would be great here. I'm using `mongoose@latest`.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24465779/389745) I decided to go down that path, and I wrote [a module that builds the aggregate query for you](https://github.com/bevacqua/limited) with a certain degree of flexibility.

Example code based on my initial question:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var limited = require('limited');
var D = require('./models/D');

function getLastDsByParent (ids, done) {
  var options = {
    model: D,
    field: 'parent',
    query: { parent : { $in: ids } },
    limit: 3,
    sort: { w: -1 }
  };
  limited(options, find);

  function find (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      done(err); return;
    }

    D
      .find({ _id: { $in: _.flatten(result, 'documents') } })
      .lean()
      .exec(done);
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't slice off the top `n` records for a parent, on the database server, and the linked answer has too many stages and involves a lot of overhead which could result in very low performance if your data set is large. If you would want top `n` records, you would end up doing `n` group and `n` unwind stages, leave alone the number of in between project stages.

Comment: It does slice the top `n` records, it's basically the linked answer made into a module. I am concerned about the overhead, for sure. I think I should measure that

Comment: If I went with your first approach I'd have to modify every single document for `parent` on every insert.

Comment: Yes i agree, you would require a bulk update. So you need to choose the best solution considering  your data set and application code(which would require some amount of rework) if you go by the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

As [pointed](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377) out, this unfortunately, this cannot be achieved using the aggregation framework of `MongoDB` that exists currently, and rightly as you mentioned, `map-reduce` would be a overkill.

But there are alternate approaches to it:

### Approach A:

- Maintain a variable denoting the level of hierarchy based on the `w`
  field, or the field by which you want to sort the result set. Once
  you add the variable to each document during insertion.
- Your documents would contain a new field called `level` which holds
  an array of a single value. We will discuss, why this needs to be an
  array and not a simple field.

Insert scripts:

```
db.collection.insert([
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 10,level:[6] },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 20,level:[5] },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 30,level:[4] },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 40,level:[3] },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 50,level:[2] },
  { parent: 'a', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 60,level:[1] },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 10,level:[4] },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 13,level:[3] },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 14,level:[2] },
  { parent: 'b', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 15,level:[1] },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 10,level:[4] },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 100,level:[3] },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 200,level:[2] },
  { parent: 'c', d1: '1', d2: '2', d3: '3', w: 300,level:[1] }
])
```

Let's assume you want to get the top `3` results based on the sort order of the `w` field for each parent. The you could easily aggregate as below:

```
var levels = [1,2,3];  // indicating the records in the range that we need to pick up,
                       // from each parent.
```

- Match all the parents that are `a` or `b`.
- Sort the records by the `w` field.
- Group by the `parent`. Once you group, all the documents for a parent
  become sub documents of the grouped record, hence allowing you to
  apply the [$redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage.
- Now apply the `$redact` stage to redact those sub documents, whose
  level is not a sub set of the levels that we seek. We kept `level` as
  an array because it makes it easier to apply the `$setIsSubset`
  operator on it. Else we would have required `$in`, which is not
  supported inside a `$cond` expression.

Code:

```
Model.aggregate(
{$match:{"parent":{$in:["a","b"]}}},
{$sort:{"w":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$parent",
         "rec":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$redact:{$cond:[{$setIsSubset:[{$ifNull:["$levels",[1]]},
                               inp]},
                 "$$DESCEND","$$PRUNE"]}},
,function(err,resp){
 // handle response
})
```

The obtained output is perfect, as we wanted:(Showing just `b` group, for keeping it shorter)

```
{
        "_id" : "b",
        "rec" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54b030a3e4eae97f395e5e89"),
                        "parent" : "b",
                        "d1" : "1",
                        "d2" : "2",
                        "d3" : "3",
                        "w" : 15,
                        "level" : [
                                1
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54b030a3e4eae97f395e5e88"),
                        "parent" : "b",
                        "d1" : "1",
                        "d2" : "2",
                        "d3" : "3",
                        "w" : 14,
                        "level" : [
                                2
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54b030a3e4eae97f395e5e87"),
                        "parent" : "b",
                        "d1" : "1",
                        "d2" : "2",
                        "d3" : "3",
                        "w" : 13,
                        "level" : [
                                3
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

### Approach B:

The redaction of the sub documents is done on the client side:

```
var result = db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"parent":{$in:["a","b"]}}},
{$sort:{"w":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$parent","rec":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}}
]).map(function(doc){
    doc.rec.splice(0,3);
    return doc;
})
```

Which is fairly slower, since all the records for each parent would be returned by `MongoDB`. The choice is yours, depending upon what suits your application.

Comment: `w` is actually a date, not just a hierarchy level

Comment: It doesnt matter. 'level' is just a field which helps identify the top records. When you insert a document you need to make sure it is set according to the field you would want to sort on.