# MongoDB - Retrieving results as array of scalar values

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

First of all I'm sorry if my english is not very good, I hope what I'm going to write will be understandable.

I have a document with this schema:

```
{
    "fields":[
         {"field": field1, "value": 1},
         {"field": field2, "value": 2},
         {"field": field3, "value": 3}
     ],
     "time": datetimeObj
},
{
    "fields":[
        {"field": field1, "value": 4},
        {"field": field4, "value": 5}
    ],
    "time": datetimeObj
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to produce a query that returns the list of values of one specific field.

For example if I want the values of the field "field1" I expect something like:

```
[1, 4]
```

For field "field2":

```
[2, 0] // 0 because it doesn't exist in the second document
```

Now I'm trying to obtain this result using aggregate operator like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $project: {
     value: {
        $filter: {
           input: "$fields",
           as: "fields",
           cond: { $eq: [ "$$fields.filed", "filed1" ] }
        }
     },
     _id : 0
  }
}
```

But what I get is much verbose than I'd like to:

```
{ 
"value" : [
    {
        "value" : NumberInt(1), 
        "filed" : "field1"
    }
]
}
{ 
 "value" : [
    {
        "value" : NumberInt(4), 
        "word" : "field1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to get the result just as an array of values? Also, is it possible to sort these values by the time field?

I'm using the python library, so it would be very usefull to have a python example of the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation query.

`$addFields` with `$cond` check if `fields` array contains (`$in`) `field1` document, if found keep `fields` array or else create a `fields` array with single `{"field": "field1", "value": 0}` document followed by `$unwind` and `$match` to keep only `field1` document.

`$sort` by `time` and `$group` and `$slice` to collect values.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "fields": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$in": [
              "field1",
              "$fields.field"
            ]
          },
          "$fields",
          [
            {
              "field": "field1",
              "value": 0
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fields"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "fields.field": "field1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "time": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "null",
      "values": {
        "$push": "$fields.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "values": {
        "$slice": [
          "$values",
          12
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I like this solution, but there is an issue to solve. I need to get last 'n' values of a certain field, 'field1' in the example, this is why I need to sort by time desc (just adjusting "time" : -1 ). The problem is that 'field1' could not exist in one of the 'n' documents I'm analysing, like 'field2' in my question, and I need to know that. Maybe I'd to write better my question. Is it possibile to adjust this solution to retrieve e.g. last 12 values (sort by time desc, limit 12) having 0 if the value does not exist?

Comment: I have adjusted the implementation to create a field 1 and value 0 document when it doesn't exist in `fields` array and added slice at the end to pick 12. Please verify.

Comment: It works great! But I've a doubt. Is it performing the execution of the slice only in the end of the pipe?
If I have a collection with 1000 documents I would prefer to sort -> slice -> perform other operations just on a subset of my 1000 documents (12 in this case).

Comment: That is genuine concern but unfortunately this is not possible. See [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-9377) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463689/mongodb-aggregation-group-restrict-length-of-array)

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description as a solution to it please try executing following aggregate query into MongoDB shell.

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$fields"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    fields: '$fields.field',
                    time: '$time'
                },
                value: {
                    $addToSet: '$fields.value'
                },

            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $match: {
                '_id.fields': 'field1'
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                "fields": '$_id.fields',
                value: '$value',
                time: '$_id.time',
                _id: 0
            }
        },

        // Stage 5
        {
            $sort: {
                time: 1
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: It works well! But what if I want to sort the result by the 'time' attribute? Should I add another stage?

Comment: @F.Aragona I have added sort stage into above aggregate query to sort resultset according to time attribute

Comment: It works but the output is no longer an array of the values, but an array of objects with the projected attributes. Maybe the sorting stage should be performed earlier?