# Reactive MongoDB Aggregation Framework Lookup stage with pipeline

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, reactivemongo

How to use Reactive MongoDB Aggregation Framework in the case when required pipeline stage isn't available?
I'm interested in [lookup stage with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries), but in documentation I found only

```
reactivemongo.api.commands.AggregationFramework.Lookup.apply(from: String, localField: String, foreignField: String, as: String)
```

### Development story

Originally code was equivalent to MongoDB JS code

```
db.tournament.aggregate([ 
  { $match : { "tid" : "abacaba"} },
  { $group : { _id : "$t" , "m" : { 
    { $sort  : { "m" : -1 } },
    $push :  {"u" : "$uid", "m" : "$m" } } 
  }},
  { $project : { "p" : { $slice : ["$m", 20]} } }
]);
```

Performance problem with this code that we pushing everything into array and discarding unneeded data only in projection stage. So after reading [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463689/mongodb-aggregation-group-restrict-length-of-array),
I rewrite it to

```
  { $match : { "tid" : "abacaba"} },
  { $sort  : { "m" : -1 } },
  { $group : { "_id" : "$t"} },
  { $lookup : {
    "from" : "tournament",
    "let" : { "i" : "$_id" },
    "pipeline" : [
      { $match : { "$expr" : { "$eq" : [ "$t", "$$i"] } } },
      { $sort  : { "m" : -1 } },
      { $limit : 20 },
      { $project : { "uid" : 1, "m" : 1} }     
    ],
    "as" : "p"
  }}
]);
```

but I stuck with translating it to Reactive MongoDB Scala code.

UPD1. I accidentally found [piece of code](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/blob/master/modules/tournament/src/main/TournamentRepo.scala#L144-L148) with necessary lookup syntax. And came to another question. How [Sharded Collection Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#sharded-collection-restrictions) looks in my case when the collection on which I run the aggregate() method is equal to from collection?

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself? Share your efforts as code. What errors are encountered? Share the traces.

Comment: @cchantep, no errors, no traces, just wonder is it possible to make [this code](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/blob/dc54ff1f95403b357c2bb27494a2f007910ad2ae/modules/tournament/src/main/PlayerRepo.scala#L52-L78) faster.

Comment: @cchantep when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above might be closed as off-topic because it is missing context.